# how to keep selected value in select box after submit or page reload were values and option are different which retrieved from db?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to keep selected particular value which was selected before the form submission. But after reloading or submisssion i did not get the previous selected value.help me!

```
     <select name="select" class="dropbtn"  onchange="this.form.submit()">
      <?php
       include 'connect.php';
       $query="SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE id =1";
       $result=mysqli_query($link_id,$query);
        while($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        { ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $data['user_id']; ?>"> <?php echo 
            $data['address']; ?> </option>
        <?php } ?>
      </select>
   <?php
      $id = null;
      if(isset($_POST['select']))
      {
       $id = $_POST['select'];
       echo $id; 
      }
   ?>
```

Comment: when re-creating your content after submission, you need to read the selected value from the input data (e.g. $_POST or $_GET data, depending) and then use that to change what you output in the `<option>`s - if the value of the option matches the selected value of the field in the input data, then add "selected" attribute to your option

Comment: @ADyson can you post the code?

Comment: It would be along the same lines as this example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50737788/populate-dropdown-from-database-and-set-default-value